# Validating form fields on Sharepoint using jQuery

Tags: jquery, validation, sharepoint

I'm using [this](http://sharepointtips-tricks.blogspot.com/2013/10/sharepoint-with-jquery-client-side-form.html) guide and http://jqueryvalidation.org/ to validate some fields in my form. It works fine, but it doesn't show correct error message. It displays field's name.

```
var validator = $("form").validate({
    errorClass: "ms-formvalidation"         
});
$("input[title='Bridge Opened']").rules("add", { date: true });     
$("input[title='Bridge Requested']").rules("add", { date: true });
```

[image: Fields]

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Need to add custom message.

```
    $("input[title='Bridge Opened']").rules("add", {
        date: true,
        messages: {
            date: "Please enter a date in the format \"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm\""
        }           
    });
```